# Create data flow graph of a basic block from Gimple representation

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, graph, dot, dataflow

the Gimple internal representation (IR) of GCC provides some data flow analysis for each basic block in the SSA (Static Single Assignment) form. I would like to take the GCC-generated Gimple file as input and generate a data flow graph for basic blocks. For example, the code below shows a simple basic block in Gimple format generated by GCC (using `-fdump-tree-cfg`).

```
...
<bb 3>:
  i2 = 0;
  goto <bb 5>;

<bb 4>: //the inner-most loop, where real computation happens
  i1.0 = i1;
  i1.1 = i1;
  D.1608 = y[i1.1];
  i2.2 = i2;
  D.1610 = w[i2.2];
  D.1611 = i1 + i2;
  D.1612 = x[D.1611];
  D.1613 = D.1610 * D.1612;
  D.1614 = D.1608 + D.1613;
  y[i1.0] = D.1614;
  i2 = i2 + 1;

<bb 5>:
  if (i2 <= 31)
    goto <bb 4>;
  else
    goto <bb 6>;
...
```

In the code above, data dependencies (which I think are called flow-dependence edges) can be seen in `bb 4`. I need to visualize the data dependence in order to analyze the data flow in each basic block in form of a data flow graph. By data flow graphs I mean graphs in which nodes in the graph represent operations like addition and multiplication, and edges represent data dependence between nodes. One option is to write a parser that takes Gimple and generates a `dot` file. I was wondering if there is already such a tool that does that. It does not seem difficult to write such a parser, but I am afraid that I might get stuck in dealing with a lot of corner cases.

Please note:
My google search was not that fruitful since the tools I found like [this](http://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html) only generate control flow graphs.